# How does android style cascade?

Tags: android, text, colors, android-actionbar

I'm new to android development. And i'm confusing about the cascading mechanism of android style. If i want to set the textColor of a actionBar. I need to do it like this.

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<!--         API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

     <!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/border</item>     
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>   
    </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#eee</item>
  </style>
```

this works fine!! but what i'm confusing is why the following doesn't work?

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<!--         API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
         <item name="android:textColor">#eee</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Styles in Android are not inherited a from wrapping/outer view (`ViewGroup`) to the wrapped/inner views, like in HTML. <del>So, setting the `android:textColor` of `AppBaseTheme` doesn't affect the style of title text of action bar.</del>

The style definition states that:

- When using `AppBaseTheme` as the style (in this case, as the theme of the activity, or all activities of the application), use `MyActionBar` as `actionBarStyle`
- When using `MyActionBar` as the style (in this case, as the style of the action bar), use `MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle` as `titleTextStyle`
- When using `MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle` as the style (in this case, as the style of the title text), use `#eee` as the `textColor`.

As you said, "When a style is applied as a theme, every View in the Activity or application will apply each style property that it supports." However, the parent style (`TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title`) defines the different `android:textColor`, so it doesn't comply one which is defined in the theme.

Comment: thanks for your rapid replies. Today i read the official development docs again carefully, and find these:-------- "A theme is a style applied to an entire Activity or application, rather than an individual View (as in the example above). When a style is applied as a theme, every View in the Activity or application will apply each style property that it supports. For example, you can apply the same CodeFont style as a theme for an Activity and then all text inside that Activity will have green monospace font."  while the actionbar might be a "special case", i need to read more about it.